# What is the volume of visits required in a test A/B?

Tags: confidence-interval, ab-test, internet

I have a client that has a web site, he want my to help improve it's conversion rate. I am currently planning an A/B test, on the service page, testing the form.

Number estimated of views on one month are 1,200 and the current conversion rate of the service page is 3.34%.

I don't know how to calculate how many visits are required to provide a 95% confidence in the results of the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Wald's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) of the confidence interval: $$p\pm\sqrt{\frac{(1-p)p}{n}}$$ So, in your case 95% confidence interval is $$\approx 3.3\%\pm 1\%$$ Solve for whatever precision you need.

For instance, in your case it's clear that you should not be reporting your conversion rate as 3.34%, because your 95% precision is over 1 percentage point. You have to report your conversion rate as 2.3-4.3% range or as 3%.

If you think your A/B test will produce the difference of more than 1% between A and B, then you're good with 1200 visits to each A and B page. If you're splitting 1200 visits to A/B, then it's not enough for 1% difference for the confidence band at 600 visits is $\pm 1.4\%$

Comment: He "[has] to report [his] conversion rate as 2.3-4.3%" ? No. His conversion rate is a known value, it's not an inference from a sample. The range applies only when he wants to see if his alternative performs "significantly" better.

Comment: @Jeff, to calculate p with 1 basis point precision they must have had 100 million visitors. This must be a popular site. Good for them

Comment: conversion rate was measured, not inferred. it's *descriptive* statistics, not inferential statistics.

Comment: It's measured on a sample. It's not given by God. That sample had some size

Comment: are you suggesting we shouldn't report descriptive statistics? if i flip a coin and it comes up heads, it's ok to report that the coin came up heads. there's no need to say "the coin came up heads 0-1 times". how is this any different than reporting sample means, one of the most common statistics in science?

Comment: When you report descriptive stats, you also should report the sample size. Simple

Comment: agreed. 3.34% conversion rate, 1200 people.

Comment: If I wouldn't care for decimal digits given the sample size, of course.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to collect data until you prove the new page is better, or, on the other hand, until you reach the limit of resources (time, visitors) you can afford for the experiment without being able to reach a decisive conclusion. If the new page is not truly better, the null hypothesis will never be disproved.

The statistical question according to this approach is "do the data collected for the new page (B) reject with a confidence of 95% the null hypothesis that its conversion rate is 3.34%?". this is readily calculated from the binomial cumulative distribution function, with p=3.34% and n and K as in the current result of your test. Note that the typical cdf formula is presented as `P(k<K)` so the result is significant if P comes out more than 95% when you replace K with the number of successes in your experiment.

Experimenting with n's and k's can help you set expectations of how long the experiment will take to prove with a high confidence.

A slight modification to this approach is if you are measuring the conversion rate of A and B in parallel. In that case, you have two sets of binomial data, and the null hypothesis that you are trying to disprove is that both datasets came from the same binomial probability p.
In this case, you need to integrate the likelihood ratio over all possible p's between 0 and 1 given the two sets of results. In practice, this can be done by looping on the probabilities:
$P(Conv.rate(A)>conv.rate(B))=\sum_x P(Conv.rate(A)=x) P(Conv.rate(B)<x)/\sum_x P(Conv.rate(A)=x)$